Third differential in the AHSS computing ko-homology.
I was wondering whether it is known what the third differential in the AHSS computing $ko$-homology is. I am trying to compute $ko_n(X)$ for some spectrum $X$ and $n$ is at most $5$.
As far as I am aware, the second differential is given by $k$-invariants (such as $Sq^2$ or $Sq^2\circ \text{red}_2$). I heard that the third differential is supposed to be a secondary cohomology operation associated to $Sq^2\circ Sq^2=0$. I do not have any experience with secondary cohomology operations; has this been worked out in detail? If so, a reference would be welcome.
